# Accessing private field in Java

Tags: java

I don't understand why I can access the `private int i` outside of the class while it's private.

```
public class Fish {

    private int i = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fish k = new Fish();
        k.i = 2; // it IS possible
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't access outside the class, main function is part of class Fish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main method is part of the Fish class isn't it?

The following doesn't work:

```
public class Fish {

    private int i = 1;

}

class Reptile{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
         Fish k = new Fish();

         k.i = 2; // Compiler error.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Access modifiers work on **class level** not on **object level**.

You are allowed to access `k.i` since the code lies within the same class as in which the member `i` is declared.

The rationale is (afaik) the following: You encapsulate the data (partly) in order to ease future maintenance and refactorings. When you refactor code, you refactor classes, not objects.

Answer (score 2):

Private means that only the defining *class* can access the variable.

Your main method is a method of the class Fish, and so it is allowed to access the variable

Answer (score 1):

This is not outside the class. You're in the same class.

You're instantiating a new instance of the same class and therefore you can access the private fields of this class.

Answer (score 0):

If this were the main method in SomeOtherClass, the same line would fail.